# How to find out name of image in imageArray of javascript in readDataUrl of phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have array of images like

```
var imgArray = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg"];
```

Here i want to know the name of image like ;

```
for(var i in imgArray) {
  if((imgArray[i].name) == "img2.jpg") {
    //display img2.jpg
  }
}
```

is it possible??
This is in phonegap so imgArray[i] will be that image in the folder ,
I cant check as u people are saying that is :

```
if(imgArray[i] == "img2.jpg") {
```

because imgArray[i] is not giving name instead it is giving that image from the folder.

```
function readDataUrl(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    imgArray.push(evt.target.result);
  }; 
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

is how i got imgArray

Answer (score 1):

Change it like this:

```
for(var i =0, len = imgArray.length; i<len ; i++) {
  if((imgArray[i]) == "img2.jpg") {
    //display img2.jpg
  }
}
```

It is better for performance then for-in.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var imgArray = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg"];
for(var i in imgArray) {
 if((imgArray[i]) == "img2.jpg") {
    // display img2.jpg
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to get the image element by its `src` attribute. On that element you can read the `name` attribute:

```
for(var i in imgArray) {
  // get the image element
  var imgElement = document.querySelector('img[src="'+i+'"]');
  // check its name property if it exists
  if(imgElement && imgElement.name == "img2.jpg") {
    //display img2.jpg
  }
}
```

Note: you should be careful with `for(var i in imgArray)` syntax: if someone adds a method in Array.property object, it is iterated, too. You'd better use

- `for(var i=0; i<imgArray.length; ++i) { ... }` (for older browsers)
- `imgArray.forEach(function(value) { ... });` (for modern browsers) see [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) reference

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
var imgArray = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg"];
for(var i in imgArray) {
  if((imgArray[i]) == "img2.jpg") {
    alert("happy");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FOR` loop to find the image name like this:

```
var imgArray = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg"];
for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    if(imgArray[i].indexOf('img2.jpg') !== -1) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

I thinks it better than `for(var i in imgArray)  {}`

Answer (score 0):

- don't use ".name" to access to item
- avoid `for...in` use with array

example:

```
var imgArray = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg"];
for(var i = 0; i<imgArray.length, i++){
   var img = imgArray[i];
   if(img = "img1.jpg"){
      ...
   }
}
```